# PHP Method not returning

Tags: php

**Hi there,**

I'm trying to work on this class, where I should save the action done by the function `addLikes()`. However, the `save()` method doesn't return a bool. It doesn't return anything. I've tried a var_dump in the controller, to no effect.

**Controller.php Function**

```
public function updateLike()
{
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $article = new Article($id);

    if($article->exists){
        $article->addLikes();
        $article->save();
    }

}
```

**Model.php addLikes()**

```
  public function addLikes() {
    $this->likes += 1;
}
```

**Model.php save()**

```
 public function save()
{
    $prepareQuery = 'UPDATE `articles` SET ';
    foreach( $this->data as $key => $value ) {
        $prepareQuery .= $key . ' = ' . $value . ', ';
    }
    $prepareQuery .= 'WHERE `id` = :id';

    $stmt = $this->DB()->conn()->prepare($prepareQuery);
    $stmt->execute([':id' => $this->id]);
    return !!$stmt->rowCount();
}
```

I Get the ID from the constructor, and I do get all other values. The problem is in the saving. What is wrong? Why doesn't it return it'S bool? Why isn't it saving correctly.

I'm working on this problem for a while now. Fixed the Fetching issues, but now it's not returning at all.

Comment: What is that double exclamation mark about? `!!` in your `save()` method?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware -- it's shorthand for `boolean`

Comment: @KIKOSoftware that's an equivalent of casting using `(bool)`, although personally I think actually casting is more readable.

Comment: @KIKO Software Seems is does just `(bool)$stmt->rowCount()`

Comment: It's boolean casting. This is the way how it's done in JS. Author does not know that he can use `(bool)` casting instead.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I get the idea. ;-) Never knew that... Yes, I prefer `(bool)` as well.

Comment: @Anquaser - are you sure that save does not return anything? Maybe you expect that `updateLike` will return a value?

Comment: Why are you scream about not return anything, if your code show that you do nothing to get what is returned by `save()`. So whats the issue? And you dont ESCAPE your values in the query! Are all values intergers here? If not fix that first.

Comment: I removed the var_dump. When I add the var_dump, it does not return anything, except when I exit with my self entered value.

Comment: There's likely an error with you dynamic sql query. Also the way you're adding likes is wrong as your now in a race condition. If two likes come in at the same time only 1 will be recorded. You should update the value in the db directly.

Comment: There will always something printed with var_dump: `var_dump(eval('return;'));`

Comment: I think JustOnUnderMillions means that an `UPDATE` does not returns rows. The MySQL manual says: "UPDATE returns the **number** of rows that were actually changed.", but `rowCount()`, if it is PDO, doesn't return that. It returns the number of row in a `SELECT`, and even that is not certain: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php

Comment: Last statemant from me: If you only want to now if the update was ok, you better check that with `$stmt->errorInfo();` and look if the error code is `0000`.

Comment: Just to note. I've added my var_dump back in `updateLike()`. `exit(var_dump($article->save()));`. The result is Empty. However, the `save()` method should return a bool, That's why I use `!!`. @JustOnUnderMillions, Thanks. I Will try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what is `$data` variable content in your class. It may have some errors, but an obvious error is in your SQL query. Your query at last may be as follows:

```
UPDATE `articles` SET Col1 = 4, Col2 = 5, WHERE `id` = 5
```

As you see the last element has an unneeded comma, so you must delete last comma to correct it. you can edit `model.php` as follows:

```
public function save()
{
    $prepareQuery = 'UPDATE `articles` SET ';
    foreach( $this->data as $key => $value )
        $prepareQuery .= $key . ' = ' . $value . ','; //I deleted space after comma
    $prepareQuery = substr($prepareQuery, 0, -1);  //this deletes the last comma
    $prepareQuery .= ' WHERE `id` = :id'; //I inserted a space at beginning
    $stmt = $this->DB()->conn()->prepare($prepareQuery);
    $stmt->execute([':id' => $this->id]);
    return !!$stmt->rowCount();
}
```

Comment: This, is what I didn't notice. Thanks. It was indeed my needed solution.